# Upload with capistrano to localhost

Tags: capistrano

I want Capistrano to **upload** a component to one of the servers in my cluster. The upload is done via **scp**. The upload command looks like this:

```
upload("...", "...", :via => :scp, :recursive => true)
```

When I am uploading to any other host, then the upload works fine.

When I try to upload to the **same server on which Capistrano itself is running**, I get the following error:

> *** upload via scp failed on [...]: SCP did not finish successfully () (SCP did not finish successfully ())

Relevant info:

Capistrano v2.9.0

ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-linux]

Answer (score 0):

Fairly sure this is because Capistrano expects the source file to be on the computer on which you've called the `cap deploy` command, and the destination to be on the computer you're deploying to (and perhaps also for them to be different computers).

If you're trying to get a file from a remote computer onto the computer on which you're running `cap deploy`, then I think you need to use `download` instead of `upload`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you're still looking for the answer, but here's how I solved it:

in the `localhost.rb` file for my project I added 2 lines underneatth the repo definition:

```
set :repository, "..."

set :copy_dir,"/tmp/temp/"

set :copy_remote_dir,"/tmp/"
```